# Magento 2 admin form save button not working in custom module

Tags: magento2, adminform, save, edit

Magento 2 i have created admin grid and form. when i am trying to add new data save button not working
add new->new form ->save and continue , save both not wokring

below is my code

```
  <?php
namespace MagePsycho\Customshipping\Block\Adminhtml\Zipcodes;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container;

class Edit extends Container
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    /**
     * Department edit block
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'zip_id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'MagePsycho_Customshipping';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_zipcodes';
 
        parent::_construct();
 
        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('MagePsycho_Customshipping::zipcodes_save')) {
            $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Save'));
            $this->buttonList->add(
                'save_and_continue',
                [
                    'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
                    'class' => 'save',
                    'data_attribute' => [
                        'mage-init' => [
                            'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit', 'target' => '#edit_form'],
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
                -100
            );
        } else {
            $this->buttonList->remove('save');
        }
 
    }
    /**
     * Get header with Department name
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('deliveryzipcodes_data')->getZipId()) {
            return __("Edit Department '%1'", $this->escapeHtml($this->_coreRegistry->registry('deliveryzipcodes_data')->getZipId()));
        } else {
            return __('New Department');
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Check permission for passed action
     *
     * @param string $resourceId
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
    }
    /**
     * Getter of url for "Save and Continue" button
     * tab_id will be replaced by desired by JS later
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getSaveAndContinueUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('zips/*/save', ['_current' => true, 'back' => 'edit', 'active_tab' => '']);
    }
 
    
}
?>
```

below is form file

```
    <?php
namespace MagePsycho\Customshipping\Block\Adminhtml\Zipcodes\Edit;

use \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
 
class Form extends Generic
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;
 
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }
    
    /**
     * Init form
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('deliveryzipcodes_form');
        $this->setTitle(__('Delivery Zipcode Information'));
    }
    
    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        /** @var \Maxime\Jobs\Model\Department $model */
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('deliveryzipcodes_data');
 
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => ['zip_id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]
        );
        
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('department_');
 
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('General Information'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
        );
        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('entity_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'entity_id']);
        }
 
        $fieldset->addField(
            'zip_code',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'zip_code', 'label' => __('Zip Code'), 'title' => __('Zip Code')]
        );
 
        $fieldset->addField(
            'weekday_price',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'weekday_price', 'label' => __('Weekday Price'), 'title' => __('Weekday Price')]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'weekend_price',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'weekend_price', 'label' => __('Weekend Price'), 'title' => __('Weekend Price')]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'workwave_zips',
            'checkbox',
            ['name' => 'workwave_zips', 'label' => __('Workwave'), 'title' => __('Workwave'),'onchange' => 'this.value = this.checked;']
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'thirdparty_zips',
            'checkbox',
            ['name' => 'thirdparty_zips', 'label' => __('Thirdparty'), 'title' => __('Thirdparty'),'onchange' => 'this.value = this.checked;']
        );
 
        
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
 
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you registered your router and set up the controller?

Comment: yes i have created router and controller.Fallowed below link
https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/layouts-and-forms-on-magento-2-admin/

Comment: @CloudySi any solution